# Angular 6 - Renderer2 - [dynamic] DOM not getting created - SELECT-Option

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-renderer2

am trying to create select option dynamically using Renderer2. at present am not able to create `<Select></Select>` element. but i can see able to see `<options>` are created.  due to some concerns am not allowed to share all snippets. apologizes for that.

Issue is: as its not creating select element. its just simply showing first element of array. i could get all elements when i console it in `ngOniti()`

no other console errors as well.

PFA.

[image]

kindly someone help me on this and point me right direction. if possible pls share working demo. after spend so many hours i found this [only](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/) .

```
    arr= ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"];
    const select = this._rend.createElement('select');
  select.name = name;
  var option = this._rend.createElement('option');      
    this._rend.appendChild(select, option);
    this._rend.appendChild(option, document.createTextNode(''));
  
    arr.forEach( aaaa=>{ 
        option = this._rend.createElement('option');        
        this._rend.appendChild(option, document.createTextNode(aaaa));
        if (aaaa === value)
          option.selected = true;
            this._rend.appendChild(select, option);
        
    })
```

Note: kindly share any other better solutions if mine is not at all good one.

Thank you so much every one.

Comment: where you are appending your `const select`. i can only see you are appending the option in select

Comment: @SheikAlthaf you can see it 5th line of code. and also i tried to append it after forEach(). no luck

Comment: what is the value of `value`. so that i can create a stackblitz for you

Comment: It's one of the param am passing from function so that I could check selected value with array and pass it to back End to save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code for your reference on creating the select options in stackblitz

```
class AppComponent {
   arr = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"];
   value = 'BBB'

     constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
       const select = renderer.createElement('select');
       select.name = name;
       var option = renderer.createElement('option');
       renderer.appendChild(select, option);
       renderer.appendChild(option, document.createTextNode(''));

       this.arr.forEach(aaaa => {
         option = renderer.createElement('option');
         renderer.appendChild(option, document.createTextNode(aaaa));
         if (aaaa === this.value) option.selected = true;
         renderer.appendChild(select, option);

       })
       renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, select);
     }
}
```

In this class I'm creating a select element with `Renderer2`
then appending the options element which is created with `Renderer2` is appended to the select element

finally i'm appending the select element to the AppComponent nativeElement

Flow

```
 Created `select
 |
 V
 Appended `Option` to select
 |
 V
 Appended `select` to the AppComponent host element
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpstnh

Comment: @Sheik Althaf i accept your answer. but some how its getting failed in requirement .

Comment: @worstCoder My review vote based on the version of this answer that hadn't anything but a little sentence plus the link.